# How to just return the email host in a single sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to figure out how to return just the host name in an email address in a single SQL statement.

For example if I have

```
 username@gmail.com
```

it should return

```
gmail
```

I have this SQL code:

```
select substr(emails, INSTR(emails, '@') + 1)
from Studentemails;
```

this returns `gmail.com`

So how do I get rid of the `.com`?

Comment: my bad. its in oracle. the code below returns nothing?

Comment: my bad this time, that was a typo. should be working now.

Answer (score 1):

```
 select substr(emails, INSTR(emails,'@')+1,INSTR(emails,'.')-INSTR(emails,'@')-1)
from Studentemails;
```

Answer (score 0):

I try this in MySQL:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTR(emails, INSTR(emails, '@') + 1), '.', 1)
FROM Studentemails
```